# How can user Algolia in my Rails app to search for a word that is also the name of my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I have integrated [Algolia search](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rails#using-the-api) in my rails application and indexed some attributes of my model. Now if I search for a string that is the same as the name of my model, no results show up.

One point of interest is that this issue only occurs the remote server. Local search works without any issues. Is there a specific way of searching for handling this use case?

Comment: What is the difference in configuration between your remote server and your local server ? If your remote server is running on `production` then maybe you could look for the culprit in your environment config file.

Comment: Looking into the config was good advice. Although, it was the Algolia default configuration that was the issue. Not that the 2 servers had different configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work. I was applying some filtering on the results. The problem was that the results were being limited to 20 items per page. It just happened that there were no records matching my custom filter among the first 20 search results. Thanks anyways!